# Is there a way to get the Complete String using a portion of it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In a GridView, the name of the table is getting generated dynamically. but it will have the dynamic Name with GridView ID gets appended.
something Like "w123443dsfnsbd32dkkd_GridView1". so first part will always keep changing whenever we reloads the grid. so I would like to get the  name of the Grid with "_GridView1", with this I would like to fetch the complete Grid Name. So Is there a way to look for this?

I tried this `var table = document.getElementById("GridView1");` but didn't work.

Code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("wcwidget_df5339c463eedb_widget_gridView1");

if (table.rows.length > 0) {


    for (var i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length; ++i) {


        if (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText == "Company1" || table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText == "Company2" ||
            table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText == "Company5" ) 
    {
            for (var k = 1; k < table.rows[i].cells.length; ++k) {
                table.rows[i].cells[k].style.fontWeight = "bold";
                table.rows[i].cells[k].style.color = "black";
            }

        }

    }

    for (var i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length; ++i) {
        if (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText == "Risk" || table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText == "Medium Risk" || table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText == "High Risk" ) {
            table.rows[i].cells[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
            table.rows[i].cells[0].style.color = "black";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that element actually a table ?  If so, I would get all table elements, then loop through them to do a match against the element ID

Comment: Kindly mark as accepted if this solves your query... Thanks

Comment: @Mike : Its a GridView. but when we look at browser console - it is rendered as a Table with tr and td.

Comment: @MikeBrockington:  I have updated my question with the code snippet, Please look into it once. As I said, the grid ID keep changing whenever we logout and login. how can I read the  data from the gridview. Any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id*='GridView1']")
```

this will return an array.

Comment: Nope. id* is for contains

Comment: Yes it will 
It will look for all the elements containing GridView1 as a string in id

Comment: Will also match against   GridView1_Sub  which _might_ be an issue.

Comment: You can use `"... $= ..."` for ends with if that is an issue

Comment: I dont think query talks about second part. User says only first part keeps changing

Comment: Hi @Amit: your code snippet is returning single cell, not an array. I am looking for an array which will make my work easy. In my Grid, it has around 150 cells is's which will have same ID appended at the end.

Answer (score 0):

On modern browsers see the @amit's answer.

If compatibility with older browsers is required:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var element = allElements[i];
    if (element.id.endsWith("_GridView1")) {
        // do something with the found element
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, but taking little time, as we have more than 20 grids on the page. It will return an array right?

Comment: @tim, what do you need specifically? Access a specific grid? Or access all grids whose ids end in "_GridView1"?

Comment: I would like to access my Grid and I need rows and cells. I have to format the rows and few cells. I mean need to apply styles (font weight, color, padding etc...)

Comment: @elds: If I can get the collection or an array, so that it will be easy for looping through.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code snippet, Please verify once. As I said, the grid ID keep changing whenever we logout and login.

Comment: @tim, Do you understand what my code does? It gets the first grid whose id ends with "_GridView1". Do you mean you can have more than 20 grids whose id ends in "_GridView1" (eg "lorem_ipsum_GridView1", "dolor_sit_amet_GridView1", "consectetur_adipiscing_GridView1" etc.)?

Comment: My Apologies. In my page there are 20 grids with different Grid ID's. and my grid id is '_GridView1'. sorry for the confusion. I got the solution. thank you.